# Ionic 2 Navigations VS Angular 2 Routes

Tags: angular, ionic2

I wondered, what are the differences between **Ionic 2 Navigations** and **Angular 2 routes**, which is better and why?. I'm still looking for an answer and I can't find one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 2 Navigations tries to simulate how you navigate on a native app, you handle the navigation with push and pop, that is all what you need, there is no need to add the complexity of a router, it has the angular router behind scene but ionic do all the work for you there.

Angular 2 Routes works like the web works, you can access to a page with the url directly from your navigation bar on your browser, and you almost always navigate by url to the next page.